# Delete all blogs on multisite

Tags: multisite, admin, scripts, customization

I'm writing a function that will delete all blogs (except the main one) from a multisite, the function is dieing whenever I call `wpmu_delete_blog` and I've got no idea why.

```
$blogs = wp_get_sites( array('limit' => 0) );
array_shift($blogs); # removes first blog from the list
foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
    $blog_id = $blog['blog_id'];
    wpmu_delete_blog( $blog_id, true);
}
```

Really I just need to run this one time, I was trying to write a php script, load wordpress (which is done successfully and recognizes the script as admin). I also tried adding this to my blog-specific plugin and it failed in the same way.

I even added a print statement to the first line of wpmu_delete_blog, the print statement doesn't get executed and the script dies when it tries to call this function.

Comment: I highly recommend using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) for such tasks as it is way easier to do. Here are the relevant commands: http://wp-cli.org/commands/site/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a work around in place. Since I was deleting all blogs with no user interaction. I created two mysql queries and ran them. The first was to drop all tables associated with the given `$blog_id` the second was to remove that row from the `wp_blogs` table.

```
$blogs = wp_get_sites( array('limit' => 0) );
array_shift($blogs); # removes first blog from the list
global $wpdb;
foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
    $blog_id = $blog['blog_id'];

    $query = "DROP TABLES ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_commentmeta, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_comments, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_links, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_options, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_postmeta, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_posts, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_term_relationships, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_term_taxonomy, ";
    $query = "wp_{$blog_id}_terms, ";

    $wpdb->query( $query );
    $wpdb->delete('wp_blogs', array( 'blog_id' => $blog_id ), array( '%d' ) );
}
```